# Group shapes or inlineshapes in ms-word using VBA (via python)

Tags: vba, ms-word, grouping, shapes

I'm trying to group shapes or inlineshapes in ms-word using VBA via python.
The reason for using python is that I am not yet familiar with VBA.
I wrote a piece of code as below but I was not successful in grouping them.

```py
import win32com.client as win32

# launch Word app. and open a source file
word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
doc = word.Document.Open(filepath)
    
# transform inlineshapes into normal shapes
for k, ils in enumerate(doc.InlineShape):
    ils.ConvertToShape()
    
array = [doc.Shapes(1).Name, doc.Shapes(2).Name]
doc.Shapes.Range(array).Group()
```

I suspected that shape object's 'WrapFormat.Type' is concerned, so I tried to insert lines such as

```
doc.Shapes(1).WrapFormat.Type = num
doc.Shapes(2).WrapFormat.Type = num
```

before grouping and changed 'num' into a certain real integer. However it didin't work.

I think there are some conditions on grouping shapes or inlineshapes successfully.
Please teach me how to execute grouping and about conditions for it.

Comment: (1) I would check the Shape.Type. For example, EMbedded OLE Objects, Linked OLE Objects and Textboxes can't be grouped. I don't have a complete list. (2) Even for a shape type that can be grouped, it can't be if the shape is set to "fix position on page" (where doc.Shapes(1).RelativeVerticalPosition is set to wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage, i.e. 1 ) rather than "Move with text", where the same property is set to wdRelativeVerticalPositionParagraph, i.e. 2. (3) possibly shapes inside content controls, or shapes created using a REF field.

Comment: @slightlysnarky  Thank you for giving useful information. I will check each condition provided.